# Setup programmatically the language code to send translated email verification - ns+angular app

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, nativescript

I'm using this plugin: https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/firebase-auth.html
to integrate my nativescript+angular mobile app with firebase authentication system.

**Is there any way to setup the language code to send a translated email verification (template provided already by firebase) ?**

I tried to setup by doing that

```
import { firebase } from '@nativescript/firebase-core'
import '@nativescript/firebase-auth'

...

let authFirebase = firebase().auth()
    
authFirebase.languageCode = 'fr'
    
authFirebase
   .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(useremail, userpassword)
   .then((cred) => {
            if (cred && !cred.user.emailVerified) { 
              // send the account activation email
              cred.user.sendEmailVerification()
            }
    })
```

but I got immediately a compilation error:

```
Cannot assign to 'languageCode' because it is a read-only property.ts(2540)
```

**Any suggestion?**

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, dude!
I think

authFirebase.setLanguageCode('fr');

is what you were looking for. It may can help you achieve your goal. I think you have already solved, but it's just to keep it here for other folks.

Comment: Careful, dude, the method setLanguageCode do not exists on the package of the nativescript plugin @nativescript/firebase-auth. So writing to nativescript development team they accept this as a bug and the issue will be fixed and provided on the next version of this plugin.

Comment: cool, thanks! what do you suggest as a good practice in that case?